# SMTP server dropped before STARTTLS completes

Tags: security, ssl, connection, starttls

When communicating with the "smtp.gmail.com" server I used the EHLO command to get the greet from gmail "at your service" response, then STARTTLS command and got "2.0.0 Ready to start TLS". After the "STARTTLS" command I start sending the email data like "MAIL FROM: %s\n", from" but when I do the server connection closes. I now realize that the server was waiting for the TLS negotiation, what TLS negotiation commands do I send to establish a handshake? I referenced Chapter 5. from the RFC document: [https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2487] for information about TLS Negotiation.

The C++ code I am using is from: [http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/35333/]

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib") //I added because of LNK2019 error
//#include <winsock2.h>  //on MSVC2008 - windows.h already includes winsock stuff    /* WSAGetLastError, WSAStartUp  */
#define snprintf _snprintf

static void sendmail_write(const int  sock,const char *str,const char *arg)
 {
    char buf[4096];

    if (arg != NULL)
        snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), str, arg);
    else
        snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), str);

    send(sock, buf, strlen(buf), 0);

// read a reply from server
    char outbuf[1024];
    int len=recv(sock,outbuf,1024,0);
    outbuf[len]='\0';
    cout <<outbuf;

}

static int sendmail(
                const char *from,
                const char *to,
                const char *subject,
                const char *body,
                const char *hostname,
        const char *user,
        const char *pass,
                const int   port
            ) {

    struct hostent *host;
    struct sockaddr_in saddr_in;
    int sock = 0;


    WSADATA wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
        return -1;
    }


    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    host = gethostbyname(hostname);

    saddr_in.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    saddr_in.sin_port        = htons((u_short)port);
    saddr_in.sin_addr.s_addr = 0;

    memcpy((char*)&(saddr_in.sin_addr), host->h_addr, host->h_length);

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&saddr_in, sizeof(saddr_in)) == -1) {
        return -2;
    }



    sendmail_write(sock, "EHLO %s\n",       "MyMailDomain");  // Should I use HELO or EHLO?

    sendmail_write(sock, "STARTTLS\n",""); // <----- starting TLS?

    sendmail_write(sock, "MAIL FROM: %s\n", from);    // from
    sendmail_write(sock, "RCPT TO: %s\n",   to);      // to
    sendmail_write(sock, "DATA\n",          NULL);    // begin data
    sendmail_write(sock, "From: %s\n",      from);
    sendmail_write(sock, "To: %s\n",        to);
    sendmail_write(sock, "Subject: %s\n",   subject);
    sendmail_write(sock, "\n",              NULL);
    sendmail_write(sock, "%s\n",            body);    // data
    sendmail_write(sock, ".\n",             NULL);    // end data
    sendmail_write(sock, "QUIT\n",          NULL);    // terminate

    closesocket(sock);

    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int ret = sendmail(

        "user@gmail.com",  // from - put an email address here
        "touser@gmail.com", // to - put an email address here
        "subject",
        "body",
        "smtp.gmail.com",
    "user@gmail.com",
    "password",
        587
    );

    if (ret != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to send mail (code: %i).\n", ret);
    else
        fprintf(stdout, "\nMail successfully sent.\n");

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: First, how do you know how many bytes you actually send?  You're not bothering to check.  Second, what SSL implementation are you using?  Setting up an SSL connection requires a lot more than just sending TLS negotiation command.s

Comment: I am new to C++ and socket programming. All I know is that the gmail-smtp server requires STARTTLS and login Authentication(user,pass). I'm not sure where to start with SSL. I thought TLS is seperate from SSL?

Comment: TLS is a later version of SSL.  See [the Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) for details on the history.  You probably should start by looking at OpenSSL for an implementation.  See https://www.openssl.org/

Comment: based on this @Eugene Mayevski 'Allied Bits https://stackoverflow.com/a/5540504/3576562 this suggest that gmail requires a  implicit SSL/TLS where STARTTLS command is sent to initiate "SSL handshake" then application-level protocol where it requests a user/password?

Comment: Assuming you're using OpenSSL, you'll have to modify a "normal" SSL connection to do STARTTLS.  Start just like you are, but once you send `STARTTLS\r\n` (note the `\r\n` instead of just `\n`), you need to call `SSL_set_fd()` to set the socket to use for SSL/TLS to the one you've already connected to, then call `SSL_connect()` to do the SSL/TLS negotiation.  Once that's successful, you switch to using `SSL_read()` and `SSL_write()` instead of `send()` and `recv()`.  Be sure to read the documentation on those functions - they can return errors at any time such that you have to retry them.

Comment: Will using Openssl mean including openSSL like "#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")" Does OpenSSL also feature a login-authentication function for gmail servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick, abbreviated "STARTTLS" example using OpenSSL, without any error checking (the proper header files are left as an exercise - that will help learn OpenSSL):

```
SSL_CTX *ctx = SSL_CTX_new( SSLv23_client_method() );
SSL *ssl = SSL_new( ctx );

connect( sock, ( struct sockaddr * ) &saddr_in, sizeof( saddr_in ) );

send( sock, "EHLO X\r\n", strlen( "EHLO X\r\n" );

// drain any reply - you can examine this - it can have useful data in it
recv( sock, buf, sizeof( buf ) );

// switch this plaintext connection over to SSL/TLS
send( sock, ". STARTTLS\r\n", strlen( ". STARTTLS\r\n" );
recv( sock, buf, sizeof( buf ) );

// now start the SSL/TLS negotiation
SSL_set_fd( ssl, sock );
int rc = SSL_connect( ssl );

...
```

After this, assuming the [`SSL_connect()`](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:SSL_connect(3)) call succeeds, you'd use [`SSL_write( ssl, void *buf, int num )`](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:SSL_write(3)) instead of `send( sock, void *buf, size_t num )`, and [`SSL_read()`](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:SSL_read(3)) instead of `recv()` to read and write data such as user names and passwords.  Note that you really need to pay attention to incomplete read and write operations, and also failures that return `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` or `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE` from `SSL_get_error()`.  For example, if `SSL_read()` fails, then `SSL_get_error()` returns `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ`, you have to retry the `SSL_read()`.

And you will want to add a lot of error checking - check *everything*, and actually do calls such as `SSL_write()` and `SSL_read()` from helper functions that handle short writes and errors, and properly retry.

Getting it working will take some trial-and-error on your part.

Comment: Great so the openssl communicates with the gmail server using the SSL_write() and SSL_read() to initiate the secure certificate and read the feedback from the server instead of the native send() and recv() for sockets?

Comment: I currently have a error: "crypto.h(659): fatal error C1070: mismatched #if/#endif pair in file" . Did you get this compilation error when including openssl?

Comment: @ComputerScience How are you compiling it?  You'd probably do better to find and use a precompiled, binary distribution.  I do know it took me a bit to get it to compile on Windows - and I used the MSVC command-line compile method. I also remember that the version of Perl available really matters - only one really works, and I don't remember offhand which one. The OpenSSL official docs: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation  See http://p-nand-q.com/programming/windows/building_openssl_with_visual_studio_2013.html for some binary distributions.

Comment: ,Not sure the version of Openssl library from CodeProject.com's implementation. It had openssl library, all changes required are in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43553483/fatal-error-openssl-e-os2-h-no-such-file-or-directory. The official openssl website had openssl-1.0.2I.tar.gz but didn't use the install file to install the library. Instead I just copied the 'crypto.h' from the openssl-1.0.2I.tar.gz compressed folder and still same error as the 'crypto.h' from the CodeProject folder. I used MSVC command-line also to build/compile my c++ socket file,

Comment: then built .exe socket program. After swapping the brackets for parentheses on every '#include openssl/', I stepped through the entire 'crypto.h' and every #ifndef was closed by a #endif , oddly '#ifndef HEADER_CRYPTO_H' starts at the beginning of the file and ends at end of file. Do I need a Perl installation to access a working openssl library?

Comment: What Openssl version did you use and how do you find a precompiled version? Also what is the file type of a binary distribution openssl; .rar, .lib, .dll?

Comment: what language did you use; native-C or C++ ?  Also I noticed that IBM's implementation also changed the include libraries to parentheses like: #include "openssl/bio.h" . See the "Headers and initialization" in link: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-openssl/  , the guy in the following link had similar issues compiling openssl with native-c or c++;
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41200177/https-with-openssl-on-linux-in-c-c

Comment: Also did you use the TCP or UDP protocol when creating your socket? Any information on your socket initialization would be helpful.